# Updating an Office 2010 Add-In to support inline response in Office 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in, office-2010, office-2013

I currently have one Add-In project that supports both 2010 and 2013 versions of Office. The only difference is the setup project I use to install the Add-In. One searches for the 2010 PIA and the other for the 2013 PIA. I'm able to support both versions this way. The only problem is that since I'm using the v4.0 libraries I can't access the tools for supporting inline response in 2013.

I currently have Office 2013 and Visual Studios 2010 installed of my machine, can I updated the references from the Office 2013 installation? I understand that if I update my project to support the inline responses, it might brake the compatibility with 2010. This is fine as I can just have two projects.

Do I need VS2012 or higher to support the Office 2013 libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this took a little while to figure out. All you need to do is delete the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` and `stdole` and add the `Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library` reference. I couldn't find the PIA for the Office 2013 originally as they show up as COM instead in .NET in the Add Reference form in VS2010.

After that, the `this.Application.ActiveExplorer()` should have inline response events. You don't need VS2012 to support the libraries. While I separated the inline response code by checking the application version, I haven't had the chance to test on Outlook 2010 to make sure it works. I'll edit this answer once I do.